# Посчитать сумму каждых m элементов вектора размером n

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Задан вектор размером `n`. Как суммировать каждые `m` значений из данного вектора? То есть первые три, вторые три и тд. На выходе получить вектор сумм размером `n / m`. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Можете добавить в вопрос пример данных и ожидаемый результат? Пример данных хорошо бы кодом :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Суммирование каждых трех элементов:

```
items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
n = len(items)
m = 3

new_items = []

for i in range(n // m):
    new_items.append(sum(items[i * m: i * m + m]))

print(new_items)  # [3, 12, 21, 30]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
result = [sum(a[i:i+m]) for i in range(0, n, m)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Общее решение.

```
def sum_norm(x, y):
    d = []
    n = len(y)
    m = len(x)
    rng = round(n/m)
    for i in range(rng):
        d.append(np.sum(y[i*m:i*m+m]))
    return d
```

Comment: Хорошо что вы сами справились :) Пара замечаний по форматированию: отступ рекомендуется 4 пробела, не используйте переменные в верхнем регистре -- они считаются константами (хотя никто не мешает их менять), многовато у вас лишних круглых скобок, как будто на лисп смотрю :) `rng = (round(n/m))` -> `rng = round(n/m)`, `D.append(np.sum(d[i*m : i*m+m)])`, в названия функций/методов в нижнем регистре, а в верхнем регистре в верблюжьей нотации называются обычно классы: `SumNorm` -> `sum_norm`

Comment: @gil9red поправила, спасибо за замечания.

Answer (score 1):

Пример векторизированного решения с использованием модуля Pandas:

```
In [235]: import pandas as pd

In [236]: v = np.random.randint(100, size=(20))

In [237]: v
Out[237]: array([84, 58, 86, 81, 36,  3, 15, 30, 82, 90, 69, 63, 80, 92, 60,  8,  8,  5, 86, 33])

In [238]: s = pd.Series(v)

In [239]: s
Out[239]:
0     84
1     58
2     86
3     81
4     36
5      3
6     15
      ..
13    92
14    60
15     8
16     8
17     5
18    86
19    33
Length: 20, dtype: int32

In [240]: m = 3

In [241]: s.groupby(np.arange(len(s)) // m).sum()
Out[241]:
0    228
1    120
2    127
3    222
4    232
5     21
6    119
dtype: int32

In [242]: s.groupby(np.arange(len(s)) // m).sum().values
Out[242]: array([228, 120, 127, 222, 232,  21, 119])

In [243]: s.groupby(np.arange(len(s)) // m).sum().values.tolist()
Out[243]: [228, 120, 127, 222, 232, 21, 119]
```